# Why are you overloading an operator that has not been defined before?

Tags: c++

In the example below, the addition operator has been overloaded:

```
class CVector {
public:
int x,y;
CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};
```

BUT would you say that the addition operator is overloaded for the type CVector, when the addition operator hasn't even been declared or defined before in this class?

Thanks!

Comment: What? Please elaborate on your question. Addition operator is being declared in the following line: `CVector operator + (const CVector&);`. Why would it need to be declared before the class?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius what I mean is... You would say that I overloaded the addition operator, right? If so, why would you say so when the addition operator hasn't even been declared or defined in CVector before? Isn't it then just declared for the first time, and therefor not overloaded?

Comment: + is already defined for integers, floats, so yours is not the first operator+ declared.

Comment: I think you're confusing overloading with overriding.

Comment: You overloading the "global" operator +.

Comment: @JakeBlandon You just repeated what you wrote in a question. I asked to _elaborate_ on why are you thinking the way, that you are. Yes, it is overloaded (albeit lacking definition, and you would get missing external symbol error if you tried to use it). Why do you think, that you need to add any additional declarations?

Answer (score 2):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) defines operator overloading briefly as

> operator overloading: Customizes the C++ operators for operands of user-defined types. Overloaded operators are functions with special function names.

So operator `+` actually is a function with a predefined name `operator+`, which is already in use for several types. When you now provide a custom implementation of `operator+` for your  user-defined type `CVector`, then this is seen as `overloading`, because you define a different implementation for a given function name for individual parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> would you say that the addition operator is overloaded for the type CVector, when the addition operator hasn't even been declared or defined before in this class?

Yes.

Let's say you have:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
```

If you use `a + b`, you are using a version of the `+` operator that is defined for `int`s.

Now, let's say you have:

```
std::string as;
std::string bs;
```

If you use `as + bs`, you are using a version of the `+` operator that is defined for `std::strings`s.  For this reason, this `+` operator is **an overload** that works with `std::string`s.

Coming to your class, let's say you have:

```
CVector v1 = { ... };
CVector v2 = { ... };
```

When you define a function that allows you to use `v1 + v2`, it is **an overload** of the `+` operator that works with `CVector`s.

It is not **an overload of the `+` operator for `CVector`s**.
It is **an overload of the `+` operator** that works with `CVector`s.